# An unfair die game.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

The three faces are A,B,and C. We are given three free rolls. In any free roll if we get A or B, the free rolls reset to 3 and three consecutive C means game over. If we get a total of 10 A's the game ends. Every B pays $1*(the total number of A's encountered till that point).

I need to determine the average no. of free rolls and the average payoff.

[I tried to model it as Markov chain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDyY0.jpg)

Comment: Hint: first forget about the A's (assume p(A)=0). Then forget about the C's (p(C)=0) and replace 10 with 2 as it's essentially the same problem, and again see if you can figure out the solution of this simpler problem. Only then consider the full problem with both conditions.

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  Say the first roll is $A$.  Do I then have three throws left or do I complete the two initially given rolls and then roll three more, for a total of five free throws remaining?

Comment: @lulu As I read it if you throw an A then you have three throws remaining.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier  I'd say either reading is plausible...

Comment: @lulu to me "reset" really means that you forget what you had and start over with the initial number $3$.

Comment: Judging by OP's Markov chain image, it looks like @Arnaud Mortier's is the interpretation in agreement with OP.

Comment: Ok, with that reading the expected length computation works well if you do it by states.  Just keep track of the number of $C's$ running and solve the resultant system of linear equations.

Comment: For reference, computer simulation gives averages of $\approx 20.4$ rolls and $\approx\$26.5$ payout

Comment: Yes! Can confirm that the exact solution below yields an average of ~ 20.41 rolls and \$26.50 payout in a game where the die is fair ($\alpha=\beta=\gamma=1/3$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key way to simplify this question is to ask "How many B's do I expect to see before I see an A, and before I see three C's consecutively."  This is a mini-game whose answer is useful for solving the overall puzzle.

You can subdivide the overall puzzle into *phases* based on how many A's you've seen so far (A=0, A=1, A=2, etc.). In each phase, you play the game and count the number of B's you see until you either lose or see another A and progress to the next phase.  The number of B's you see does not depend on what phase you're in—it neatly factors out.

As shown below, you can calculate this factor $E$ (the expected number of B's before seeing either an A or three consecutive C's) and $P$ (the probability that the mini-game ended with seeing an A rather than seeing three consecutive C's), in which case the expected payout can be expressed as:
$$T = E \left[0 + P + 2P^2 + 3P^3 + \ldots + 9P^9\right]$$

And with a similar trick, if $\ell$ is the expected number of dice rolls in a given phase, then the expected number of dice rolls is:

$$L = \ell \left[1 + P + P^2 + P^3 + \ldots + P^9\right]$$

---

- Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ denote the probabilities of rolling an A, B, and C respectively. If you have three throws remaining, then when you roll the die you might get:

  - An A, with probability $\alpha$. You get no B's and the mini-game ends.
  - A B, with probability $\beta$. You get one B, and return to the original state (three throws remaining, no consecutive C's).
  - Some number of C's in a row.  With probability $\gamma^3$, you see three in a row and lose.  With probability $\gamma^2 \alpha$, you see two C's followed by an A, and the mini-game ends. With probability $\gamma^2\beta$, you see two C's followed by a B and return to the original state. With probability $\gamma \alpha$, the game ends. With probability $\gamma\beta$, you see a C and a B and return to the original state.
  - These are all the possibilities.
- Overall, if $E$ denotes the expected number of B's seen, the above cases give the expectation formula:

  $$E = (\gamma^3 + \gamma^2\alpha + \gamma \alpha + \alpha)\cdot 0 + (\gamma^2\beta + \gamma\beta + \beta) \cdot (1+E)$$
  $$E = (1+\gamma +\gamma^2)\beta  + (1+\gamma + \gamma^2)\beta E$$
  $$E = \frac{\beta(1+\gamma + \gamma^2)}{1-\beta(1+\gamma+\gamma^2)}$$
- We also need the probability that such a mini-game ends with seeing an A, as opposed to seeing three C's consecutively. By a similar formula, this probability is:

  $$P =  \alpha (1 + \gamma + \gamma^2) + \beta(1 + \gamma + \gamma^2) P + 0 \cdot \gamma^3 $$ 
  $$P = \frac{\alpha (1+\gamma+\gamma^2)}{1-\beta(1+\gamma+\gamma^2)}$$
- Now, we can solve the overall expected cost problem.

  - If you have seen $m$ A's so far, the expected number of B's until you see the next A (or lose the game) is $E$ (as computed above).  The expected payout in that case is $mE$.  Then, with probability $P$ you continue the game with $m+1$ A's seen so far, otherwise you have seen 3 C's in a row and lost.
  - When the game ends after seeing 10 A's, the total expected payout $T$ is therefore:

  $$T = E \left[P + 2P^2 + 3P^3 + \ldots + 9P^9\right]$$
- We can solve the expected length problem (expected number of tosses) using the same approach; if $\ell$ denotes the expected number of dice thrown before you see an A or three consecutive C's, then by my math:

  $$\ell = \gamma^3(3) + \gamma^2\alpha(3) + \gamma\alpha(2) + \alpha(1) + \gamma^2\beta(3+\ell) + \gamma\beta(2+\ell) + \beta(1+\ell)$$

  $$\ell = 3\gamma^3 + \left[3\gamma^2 + 2\gamma + 1\right](\alpha+\beta) +  \left[ \gamma^2  +\gamma + 1 \right]\beta \ell $$

  $$\ell = \frac{3\gamma^3 + (3\gamma^2 + 2\gamma + 1)(1-\gamma)}{1-(\gamma^2  +\gamma + 1)\beta}$$
  Then we can determine the expected number of dice $L$ thrown during the *overall* game, using the quantity $P$ computed above:

  $$L = \ell (1 + P + P^2 + P^3 + \ldots + P^9)$$

Comment: Thanks!! I have a doubt regarding the expected length calculation. The expected length should depend on α too, as the game ends when we get 10 As.

Comment: @s0RRy Good observation. In the length calculation, I didn't take into account the fact that the game would end after 10 A's. To solve it, you can apply the same trick as used in the expected cost calculation: find the expected length until you either see one A or three C's.

Comment: @s0RRy Updated.